# creating jQuery plugin with nested settings/options

Tags: jquery, plugins

I want to create a jQuery plugin, and it will have nested settings/options.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.generateText = function (options) {
        // Establish our default settings
        var settings = $.extend ({
            json: [{
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Name",
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Name2",
            }]
        },
        options);
        $(settings.json).each(function () {
            $(this).append('<div class="text" data-text-id="' + settings.json.id + '" data-text-name="' + value.name + '" ></div>');
        });
    }
}
(jQuery));
```

and in index i have declaration of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').generateText();
});
```

but it does not work. I do not know what to do to get it working. 
Can anyone help me

I've changed te each function like you have suggest but it still don't work (it don't show any `<div class="text">` with `data-text-id` or `data-text-name`

Comment: Give a detailed explanation (including any error messages) of how it does not work. You should also provide sample inputs and what the related expected output is.

Comment: Well for one thing, `settings.json.id` is not valid. You probably want `settings.json[0].id`, or perhaps you should have used `$(settings.json).each(function () { ... });`. There's a bunch of peculiar stuff with that each() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the plugin written as would be appropriate. You need to recognize that there are nested loops here, and you need to read through all the comments. I have also provided a **[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K6MXu/)**.

Also, as an aside, you should know that this is not using JSON at all.  JSON is a string of serialized data. You're using a JS array literal which contains two JS object literals which each have two properties.
JSON looks similar because it borrows the syntax...but JSON is a STRING. If you don't have a string, you don't have JSON in your current context. If you don't have to parse it--it isn't JSON.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.generateText = function (options) {
        // `generateText` is a function, which is its own scope and context for `this`

        // Your settings (which do not actually contain JSON, by the way...)
        var settings = $.extend (
            {
                json: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'Name',
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Name2',
                    }
                ]
            },
            options
        );

        // In the function, `generateText`, `this` refers to the instance of jQuery which gets created when the plugin runs.
        // It contains the collection of elements which matched the DOM query when you ran it. Plugins should operate on all
        // DOM elements in the container, and return the entire collection for chaining. Since `$.fn.each` will iterate and returns
        // the collection, we can use it and return its own return to accomplish both purposes

        return this.each(function () {
            // Now we're in a new function--one which is being run for every element which was in the collection. Inside of a function
            // which is passed to `$.fn.each`, `this` refers to the raw DOM element being acted on for that iteration. We'll need to use
            // it in another scope a little lower, so we need to alias it:
            var ele = this;

            // `$.each` is a little different than `$.fn.each`. We pass it two args--the thing to iterate (the array from your so-called
            //  JSON in this case), and a function to run on each of the items as we iterate.
            $.each(settings.json, function () {
                // Ok, in a new function, so a new scope for `this` (...good thing we aliased the above `this` as `ele` since we need to use it.)
                // In this function `this` is the item from `settings.json` on the current iteration. You want things from it, and you want to
                // append to the element form above. Remember, `ele` was the raw DOM element for that iteration. Now we pass it to jQuery to
                // become a new collection which we can act on by appending a new div with some data attrs which come from the current item
                $(ele).append(
                    $('<div />')
                        .addClass('text')
                        .data('text-id', this.id)
                        .data('text-name', this.name)
                );
            });
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```